# I have using redux but api called multiple time through connect hook

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my code

```
const mapStateToProps = ({current, defaultdata, country, userorder, category, earlyaccess, stockdetail}: IRootState) => ({
  uuid: current.uuid,
  isAuthenticated: current.isAuthenticated,
  defaultData: (pageName == 'category' || pageName == 'favorite') ? category.categorydata : defaultdata.defaultdata,
  selectDataSetID: defaultdata.setdefaultdata,
  selectCountryFullName: country.selectcountryfullname,
  userorder: userorder.userorder,
  earlyAccessAuthFlag: earlyaccess.earlyAccessAuthFlag,
  earlyAccessAuthUrl: earlyaccess.earlyAccessAuthUrl,
  totalStock: stockdetail.userstock
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  checkAuthenticationConnect: checkAuthentication,
  getDefaultData: getdefaultdataset,
  getUserOrderData: editUserOrders,
  getIDCategoryData: getcatid,
  earlyAccessInfo: getearlyaccessinfo,
  getUserStockData: getstock,
  getAllFooterLinks:getsharelinks,
  refreshCountryList: getdatasetcountry
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

But every action is calling multiple time.
Can anyone please help me out how to stop multiple api calling?

Comment: use Reselect - Simple “selector” library for Redux https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Answer (score 0):

you are not connecting your dispatch functions right.

mapDispatchToProps function must return object which have all your actions.

take a look at the docs:
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

```
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  `return {
   checkAuthenticationConnect: dispatch({type: //action type}),
   
    // must pass an object contains the type property as an argument to the dispatch function
    increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
    decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
    reset: () => dispatch({ type: 'RESET' })
  }
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code like below
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => {
    return {
        logOutConnect: () => dispatch(logOut()),
        getUserOrderData: (userID: any) => {dispatch(editUserOrders(userID))},
        getUserStockData: (userID: any) => {dispatch(getstock(userID))},
    }
};
Still multiple api calling.